# Debug without handheld

Tags: debugging, adb, wear-os

I was trying to debug over Bluetooth but I was getting the localhost:4444 offline issue...
So I went and erased all data from google play services. After that, my watch was forgotten by my handheld...
I have some important files on my watch that I NEED TO KEEP...

Is there any way of connecting the watch via adb WITHOU THE HANDHELD???

Allready tried tcpip connection but adb was unnable to connnect to the ip of my watch

[image]

ps: My watch is a Moto 360 sport (no cable connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for a watch without a cable connection, there's no way to connect `adb` without some sort of proxy through the handheld. It is possible to connect `adb` over Wifi, but you need another `adb` connection first to get that started (AFAIK) - which brings you back to the BT-via-handheld connection.

There's no reason why you should need to be clearing data from Play Services on a regular basis - but as you discovered, that's where Android Wear keeps its data about the phone-watch connection. So if you don't want to factory-reset your watch, *don't do that*.

The reality is that `adb` to Wear is just incredibly painful over Bluetooth, making a watch like the 360 a bad choice as a development device. I'd suggest doing as much debugging as you can using the emulators, and if you can afford it, get another watch with a hardwired connection. You can pick up a secondhand ZenWatch or G Watch R pretty cheap these days.